# Python, numpy, einsum multiply a stack of matrices

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, multiplication

For performance reasons,

I'm curious if there is a **way to multiply a stack of a stack of matrices**.  I have a 4-D array (500, 201, 2, 2).  Its basically a 500 length stack of (201,2,2) matrices where for each of the 500, I want to multiply the adjacent matrices using einsum and get another (201,2,2) matrix.

I am only doing matrix multiplication on the [2x2] matrices at the end.  Since my explanation is already heading off the rails, I'll just show what I'm doing now, and also the 'reduce' equivalent and why its not helpful (because its the same speed computationally).  Preferably this would be a numpy one-liner, but I don't know what that is, or even if its possible.

## Code:

```
Arr = rand(500,201,2,2)

def loopMult(Arr):
    ArrMult = Arr[0]
    for i in range(1,len(Arr)):
        ArrMult = np.einsum('fij,fjk->fik', ArrMult, Arr[i])
    return ArrMult

def myeinsum(A1, A2):
    return np.einsum('fij,fjk->fik', A1, A2)

A1 = loopMult(Arr)
A2 = reduce(myeinsum, Arr)
print np.all(A1 == A2)

print shape(A1); print shape(A2)

%timeit loopMult(Arr)
%timeit reduce(myeinsum, Arr)
```

#### Returns:

```
True
(201, 2, 2)
(201, 2, 2)
10 loops, best of 3: 34.8 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 35.2 ms per loop
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Things are functional, but when I have to iterate this over a large series of parameters, the code tends to take a long time, and **I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid the 500 iterations through a loop.**

Comment: just to let you know, using `np.cumprod(np.einsum('fij,afjk->afik', Arr[0], Arr), axis=0)[-1]` gives you the same result but your solution is still faster... maybe this can give you some insight...

Comment: I've never used it, and my understanding of what exactly it does is murky, so this may not even make sense... but have you looked at Theano?

Comment: If `Arr` is `(n,2,2)`, this calculation is `Arr[0].dot(Arr[1]).dot(Arr[2])...`

Comment: If `A` is `(5,2,2)`, then this calc is `np.einsum('ij,jk,kl,lm,mn', *A)`

Comment: I think all of these answers get at the heart of my question.  Thanks for the tip about cumprod.  Its clean, but without a speed improvement.  As for Theano, I think that's beyond scope for me.  hpaulj, your answers seem to imply that there is not a dynamic way to use einsum in this manner.  If I know the first dimension of the array (which I don't always) then I could hard code a string for the einsum indices, but probably limited by the alphabet no?  If I don't know the indices I would have to dynamically generate an index string, and again I'm limited by the alphabet.

Comment: @SaulloCastro Actually that does not give you the same answer, as can be seen from np.allclose(loopMult(Arr), np.cumprod(np.einsum('fij,afjk->afik', Arr[0], Arr), axis=0)[-1]) --> False. I doubt that you can make this any faster, apart from reimplementing in C. The reason is that you are looping over quite large blocks of your array at a time, so that the lopping does not introduce much overhead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do this efficiently using numpy (the `cumprod` solution was elegant, though). This is the sort of situation where I would use `f2py`. It's the simplest way of calling a faster language that I know of and only requires a single extra file.

fortran.f90:

```
subroutine multimul(a, b)
  implicit none
  real(8), intent(in)  :: a(:,:,:,:)
  real(8), intent(out) :: b(size(a,1),size(a,2),size(a,3))
  real(8) :: work(size(a,1),size(a,2))
  integer i, j, k, l, m
  !$omp parallel do private(work,i,j)
  do i = 1, size(b,3)
    b(:,:,i) = a(:,:,i,size(a,4)) 
    do j = size(a,4)-1, 1, -1
      work = matmul(b(:,:,i),a(:,:,i,j))
      b(:,:,i) = work
    end do
  end do
end subroutine
```

Compile with `f2py -c -m fortran fortran.f90` (or `F90FLAGS="-fopenmp" f2py -c -m fortran fortran.f90 -lgomp` to enable OpenMP acceleration). Then you would use it in your script as

```
import numpy as np, fmuls
Arr = np.random.standard_normal([500,201,2,2])
def loopMult(Arr):
  ArrMult = Arr[0]
  for i in range(1,len(Arr)):
    ArrMult = np.einsum('fij,fjk->fik', ArrMult, Arr[i])
  return ArrMult
def myeinsum(A1, A2):
  return np.einsum('fij,fjk->fik', A1, A2)
A1 = loopMult(Arr)
A2 = reduce(myeinsum, Arr)
A3 = fmuls.multimul(Arr.T).T
print np.allclose(A1,A2)
print np.allclose(A1,A3)
%timeit loopMult(Arr)
%timeit reduce(myeinsum, Arr)
%timeit fmuls.multimul(Arr.T).T
```

Which outputs

```
True
True
10 loops, best of 3: 48.4 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 48.8 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.82 ms per loop
```

So that's a factor 8 speedup. The reason for all the transposes is that `f2py` implicitly transposes all the arrays, and we need to transpose them manually to tell it that our fortran code expects things to be transposed. This avoids a copy operation. The cost is that each of our 2x2 matrices are transposed, so to avoid performing the wrong operation we have to loop in reverse.

Greater speedups than 8 should be possible - I didn't spend any time trying to optimize this.