# Matrix multiply a numpy array of matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am expanding code designed to perform a function on 2 vectors so that it instead handles 2 arrays of vectors. I was using `numpy.dot` to take the product of two 3x3 matrices.  Now I want to do this with an array of 3x3 matrices.  I was not able to figure out how to do this with `numpy.einsum` but I think that is what I need, I'm just struggling to understand how it works.

Here is an example of what I want using a loop.  Is there a way to do this without the loop?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> print m
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
>>> m2 = np.zeros(m.shape)
>>> for i in length(m):
        m2[i] = np.dot(m[i],m[i])
>>> print m2
    array([[[   15.,    18.,    21.],
            [   42.,    54.,    66.],
            [   69.,    90.,   111.]],

           [[  366.,   396.,   426.],
            [  474.,   513.,   552.],
            [  582.,   630.,   678.]],

           [[ 1203.,  1260.,  1317.],
            [ 1392.,  1458.,  1524.],
            [ 1581.,  1656.,  1731.]]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a `numpy.einsum` syntax in this post [Python, numpy, einsum multiply a stack of matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981180/python-numpy-einsum-multiply-a-stack-of-matrices) which does what I want.  I am not clear on why that works and want to understand how to construct the indexing strings for future uses.

```
>>> print np.einsum('fij,fjk->fik', V, V)
    [[[  15   18   21]
      [  42   54   66]
      [  69   90  111]]

     [[ 366  396  426]
      [ 474  513  552]
      [ 582  630  678]]

     [[1203 1260 1317]
      [1392 1458 1524]
      [1581 1656 1731]]]
```

Comment: Are you mainly interested in constructing the indexing strings, or want a more in depth understanding of how `einsum` operates?  The source code is C.

Comment: I want to understand how to construct the indexing strings (just clarified that in the post).

Comment: These test examples may help: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/tests/test_einsum.py

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Pandas.  In the example below, 'p' is equivalent to your 'm' and is a 3D representation of the data.  Using list comprehension, p2 calculates the dot product of each matrix.  For comparison purposes, the results are then converted back to a list of numpy arrays.

```
import pandas as pd

%%timeit
m = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
p = pd.Panel(m)
p2 = [p[i].dot(p[i]) for i in p.items]

1000 loops, best of 3: 846 µs per loop

m2 = [p2[i].values for i in p2.items]
print(m2)

[array([[ 15,  18,  21],
       [ 42,  54,  66],
       [ 69,  90, 111]]), 
array([[366, 396, 426],
       [474, 513, 552],
       [582, 630, 678]]), 
array([[1203, 1260, 1317],
       [1392, 1458, 1524],
       [1581, 1656, 1731]])]
```

Numpy is much faster, however.

```
%%timeit
np.einsum('fij,fjk->fik', m, m)

100000 loops, best of 3: 5.01 µs per loop
```

Comparing it straight to np.dot:

```
%%timeit
[np.dot(m[i], m[i]) for i in range(len(m))]

100000 loops, best of 3: 6.78 µs per loop
```

Comment: I am just starting to use pandas so it is good to see how I would use this.  The example in pandas uses a loop though so it would be better to compare it to the `numpy.dot` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but in case someone ends up here in 2023 (or later)...
`matmul` does what you want:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> print(np.matmul(m, m))
[[[  15   18   21]
  [  42   54   66]
  [  69   90  111]]

 [[ 366  396  426]
  [ 474  513  552]
  [ 582  630  678]]

 [[1203 1260 1317]
  [1392 1458 1524]
  [1581 1656 1731]]]
```

If the two operands passed to [`matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) are N-dimensional arrays (with N>2), they are treated as stacks of matrices stored in the last two dimensions. For example `np.matmul(a, b)` where `a` is 4×6×5×2 and `b` is 4×6×2×3 (i.e. `a` and `b` are 4×6 stacks of 5×2 and 2×3 matrices, respectively) gives a 4×6 stack of 5×3 matrices stored in a 4×6×5×3 ndarray.