# optimal numba implementations for matrix multiplication depends significantly on matrix size

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numba

This question relates to one I posted awhile back:
[Python, numpy, einsum multiply a stack of matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981180/python-numpy-einsum-multiply-a-stack-of-matrices)

I am trying to understand why I get the speedups I get with Numba when used in a particular manner when **multiplying a stack of a stack of matrices**.  As before, I am putting in a (500,201,2,2) array, multiplying the (2x2) matrices at the end along the first axis (so 500 multiplications), to get a (201,2,2) array as the result.

Here is the Python code:

```
from numba import jit  # numba 0.24, numpy 1.9.3, python 2.7.11

Arr = rand(500,201,2,2)

def loopMult(Arr):
    ArrMult = Arr[0]
    for i in range(1,len(Arr)):
        ArrMult = np.einsum('fij,fjk->fik', ArrMult, Arr[i])
    return ArrMult

@jit(nopython=True)
def loopMultJit(Arr):
    ArrMult = np.empty(shape=Arr.shape[1:], dtype=Arr.dtype)
    for i in range(0, Arr.shape[1]):
        ArrMult[i] = Arr[0, i]
        for j in range(1, Arr.shape[0]):
            ArrMult[i] = np.dot(ArrMult[i], Arr[j, i])
    return ArrMult

@jit(nopython=True)
def loopMultJit_2X2(Arr):
    ArrMult = np.empty(shape=Arr.shape[1:], dtype=Arr.dtype)
    for i in range(0, Arr.shape[1]):
        ArrMult[i] = Arr[0, i]
        for j in range(1, Arr.shape[0]):
            x1 = ArrMult[i,0,0] * Arr[j,i,0,0] + ArrMult[i,0,1] * Arr[j,i,1,0]
            y1 = ArrMult[i,0,0] * Arr[j,i,0,1] + ArrMult[i,0,1] * Arr[j,i,1,1]
            x2 = ArrMult[i,1,0] * Arr[j,i,0,0] + ArrMult[i,1,1] * Arr[j,i,1,0]
            y2 = ArrMult[i,1,0] * Arr[j,i,0,1] + ArrMult[i,1,1] * Arr[j,i,1,1]
            ArrMult[i,0,0] = x1
            ArrMult[i,0,1] = y1
            ArrMult[i,1,0] = x2
            ArrMult[i,1,1] = y2
    return ArrMult

A1 = loopMult(Arr)
A2 = loopMultJit(Arr)
A3 = loopMultJit_2X2(Arr)

print np.allclose(A1, A2)
print np.allclose(A1, A3)

%timeit loopMult(Arr)
%timeit loopMultJit(Arr)
%timeit loopMultJit_2X2(Arr)
```

Here is the output:

```
True
True
10 loops, best of 3: 40.5 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 36 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 808 µs per loop
```

In the prior question, the accepted answer showed that with f2py there was a speedup of 8x without detailed optimization.  Here, with Numba, I get about 10% speedup using numba over an einsum loop, but I get 45x speedup if instead of using np.dot in the loop, I simply do the 2x2 matrix multiplication by hand.  Why is this?  I should mention I have implemented both of these jit functions with proper type signatures as guvectorize versions as well, which basically provides the same speedup factors, so I left them out.  Also speedup from iterating over a 201,500,2,2 matrix is minimal.

Comment: I think it's just that there's a reasonably Python overhead to calling `np.dot` (checking types, allocating numpy arrays, etc). Although `np.dot` is quite optimised, a 2x2 array is tiny and not worth the overhead. Thus you can easily by doing it yourself with numba (which skips all the the Python overhead). You'd probably find `np.dot` quite hard to beat on (say) 100x100 matrix multiplication.

Comment: I think overhead from BLAS and boilerplate. Check [this file](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/0.24.0/numba/targets/linalg.py) in the Numba source code. And also generality. Normally matrix multiplication consists of at least 3 loops, but you unrolled them all in `loopMultiJit_2x2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Comments have responded that the speedup is just due to python overhead, and I think that's right.  The overhead is mostly function calls, but also for loops, and np.dot has some extra overhead on top of that.  I set up a Naive dot product function:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def dot(mat1, mat2):
    s = 0
    mat = np.empty(shape=(mat1.shape[1], mat2.shape[0]), dtype=mat1.dtype)
    for r1 in range(mat1.shape[0]):
        for c2 in range(mat2.shape[1]):
            s = 0
            for j in range(mat2.shape[0]):
                s += mat1[r1,j] * mat2[j,c2]
            mat[r1,c2] = s
    return mat
```

Then I set up to functions to multiply the arrays, one which calls the dot function and one which has the dot function built into the loop, so that it is executed without an extra function call:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def loopMultJit_dot(Arr):
    ArrMult = np.empty(shape=Arr.shape[1:], dtype=Arr.dtype)
    for i in range(0, Arr.shape[1]):
        ArrMult[i] = Arr[0, i]
        for j in range(1, Arr.shape[0]):
            ArrMult[i] = dot(ArrMult[i], Arr[j, i])
    return ArrMult

@jit(nopython=True)
def loopMultJit_dotInternal(Arr):
    ArrMult = np.empty(shape=Arr.shape[1:], dtype=Arr.dtype)
    for i in range(0, Arr.shape[1]):
        ArrMult[i] = Arr[0, i]
        for j in range(1, Arr.shape[0]):
            s = 0.0
            for r1 in range(ArrMult.shape[1]):
                for c2 in range(Arr.shape[3]):
                    s = 0.0
                    for r2 in range(Arr.shape[2]):
                        s += ArrMult[i,r1,r2] * Arr[j,i,r2,c2]
                    ArrMult[i,r1,c2] = s
    return ArrMult
```

Then I can run 2 comparisons: 2x2 arrays, and 10x10 arrays.  With these I get some idea of the penalties paid for function calls in general, and for the np.dot function call in particular, and the gains from BLAS optimizations in np.dot:

```
print "2x2 Time Test:"
Arr = rand(500,201,2,2)
%timeit loopMult(Arr)
%timeit loopMultJit(Arr)
%timeit loopMultJit_2X2(Arr)
%timeit loopMultJit_dot(Arr)
%timeit loopMultJit_dotInternal(Arr)

print "10x10 Time Test:"
Arr = rand(500,201,10,10)
%timeit loopMult(Arr)
%timeit loopMultJit(Arr)
%timeit loopMultJit_dot(Arr)
%timeit loopMultJit_dotInternal(Arr)
```

which yields:

```
2x2 Time Test:
10 loops, best of 3: 55.8 ms per loop  # einsum
10 loops, best of 3: 48.7 ms per loop  # np.dot
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 ms per loop  # 2x2
10 loops, best of 3: 28.3 ms per loop  # naive dot, separate function
100 loops, best of 3: 2.58 ms per loop  # naive dot internal

10x10 Time Test:
1 loop, best of 3: 499 ms per loop  # einsum
10 loops, best of 3: 91.3 ms per loop  # np.dot
10 loops, best of 3: 170 ms per loop  # naive dot, separate function
10 loops, best of 3: 161 ms per loop  # naive dot internal
```

I suppose the take home messages are:

- einsum is nice if you're not using numba, or need one-liners, but for matrix multiplication, there are faster options
- if you're working with small matrices, it can be faster to do things by hand and not call separate functions
- for large matrices, there is a reason BLAS was invented, and in fact, speedups are quite noticeable at sizes as small as 10x10.